# Extract all numbers from 1 cell to many cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a field with numbers separated by two different characters. I am attempting to split these numbers in to their own field.

Current Data Example:

```
A
----
25-29
18-20,22,2
3,6
5,16-19
2-5,9-12
1,2,3,4
```

Expected Results

B-E would handle numbers on either side of "-"

F-I would handle any possible numbers by themselves

```
B     |  C     |  D     |  E     |  F     |  G     |  H     |  I 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
25       29
18       20                         22       2
                                    3        6
16       19                         5
2        5        9        12   
                                    1        2        3        4
```

I have tried using different combinations of MID LEFT FIND and I can't seem to figure this out. I know all 8 columns need a different formula but I am having the hardest time getting this figured out.

Any help on this is soo far beyond appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: So does `A1` actually holds all these numbers in the single cell or just `25-29`?

Comment: Sorry Let me fix that.

Comment: Each line break is a different row.

Comment: I don't think this can be achieved with simple formulas. There are too many logics. With VBA it's another story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the newest ms365's BETA-functions, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=LET(X,TEXTSPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","*"),","),Y,EXPAND(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN("*",,FILTER(X,ISERROR(--X),"*")),"*"),,4,""),Z,FILTER(X,ISNUMBER(--X),""),HSTACK(Y,Z))
```

Or, a little less verbose:

```
=LET(X,EXPAND(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"-",",",,""),,2,""),HSTACK(EXPAND(IFERROR(TOROW(FILTER(X,INDEX(X,0,2)<>"")),""),,4,""),TOROW(FILTER(X,INDEX(X,0,2)="",""))))
```

---

For those without `TEXTSPLIT()` but with office365:

```
=LET(str,"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","*")&",a*a,a*a",",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>",X,FILTERXML(str,"//s[.*0!=0][position()<3]"),Y,IFERROR(FILTERXML(str,"//s[.*0=0]"),""),SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("*",,X,Y),"*","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")),"a",""))
```

---

For those without ms365, but with Excel 2019, they can use this CSE-formula and start dragging:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("*",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-","*")&",a*a,a*a",",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0!=0][position()<3]"),IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.*0=0]"),"")),"*","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s["&COLUMN(A1)&"]"),"a",""),"")
```

Comment: Well done. I had misinterpreted the fourth line, I thought the 5 went to the next line.

Comment: When I try this I get an error stating the function isnt valid and it highlights FILTER

Comment: Do I need any add-ins for this?

Comment: @Jordan you need Office 365 Excel with the beta Channel as TEXTSPLIT is only available in Beta at the moment.

Comment: @Jordan, I should've mentioned the above. Added two other alternatives just in case.

Comment: Ive tried all 3 on two different devices one with 365 the other without. The first two give me a #NAME error and the last just is blank. Ill keep messing with it though. Thank you.

Comment: Are you on a PC, Mac, or the web? @Jordan

Comment: Mac with 365. PC with Excel 2016 (I cant upgrade it, its not my device)

Comment: Only the first will work on the mac 365 and only if you have insider beta channel.  The third will work on the PC With 2016 if you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode then copy over and down. @Jordan

Comment: @ScottCraner, I'm not sure if `TEXTJOIN()` is available with 2016 though, the last one might show blank for OP because  of `IFERROR()`.

Comment: @JvdV Yup I missed that and got hung up on the filterxml.  You are correct, none of them will work for 2016,